# What's the difference between "insulated" and "isolated"?

Tags: meaning, differences, meaning-in-context, synonyms

I don't know the difference because they have the same meaning.

Comment: What did your dictionary say? (their definitions are certainly different)

Answer (score 3):

***Insulated* has the meaning of protected, while *isolated* has the meaning of separated.**

> "If I "isolate" someone I might put them in a room, shut the door, not
>   allow people to see them, prevent them from looking out.
>
> If I "isolate" something I am segregating or separating it from the
>   rest because of some problem it might have. Its being kept apart.
>
> If I "insulate" something I might put some material around it to keep
>   the warmth in, or the cold out. I am protecting it.
>
> A person can also be "insulated"... if you protect them from the
>   world, keep them from hearing bad news."

Answer (score 1):

> Use the verb **[insulate](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=insulate%20meaning%27&hl=en-IN&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l=)**- when you wish to impy "protection from
>   heat, cold, or noise," by surrounding with (insulating) material
>
> When you remove or set apart one thing from others, you **isolate**
>   it. You could isolate yourself from people by living in a remote
>   countryside.