# How did it happen that there are two different words "insulation" and "isolation" for virtually the same concept?

Tags: etymology, loanwords, historical-change

This question is *not* about the meaning of and the difference between the words ***insulation*** and ***isolation***, it has been already answered here: [What's the difference between "insulated" and "isolated"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/233490/73094) and here [Difference between "isolated" and "insulated"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/65514/73094).

In other languages these two concepts are usually expressed by one single word.

- http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/aislamiento
- http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/isolieren
- http://slovnik.seznam.cz/en/?q=izolace
- http://en.bab.la/dictionary/polish-english/izolacja
- http://www.fincd.com/finnish/erist%E4minen.html

They have practically the same etymology:

- http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=isolate

  > "standing detached from others of its kind," 1740, a rendering into English of French *isolé* "isolated" (17c.), from Italian *isolato*, **from Latin *insulatus* "made into an island**", from *insula* "island" (see *island* (n.)). English at first used the French word (*isole*, also *isole'd*, c. 1750), then after *isolate* (v.) became an English word, *isolated* became its past participle.
- http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=insulate

  > 1530s, "make into an island," **from Late Latin *insulatus* "made like an island**", from *insula* "island" (see *isle*). Sense of "place in an isolated situation, cause (someone or something) to be detached from surroundings" is from 1785. Electrical/chemical sense of "block from electricity or heat" (by interposition of a non-conductor) is from 1742. Related: *Insulated*; *insulating*.

Do I understand properly that the word was imported into English *twice*, once directly from Latin (1530), and then again via French (1740)? Then it is funny that the notion which sounds more modern is carried by the older word. Or was it one word which somehow "split" into two?

Comment: In English we need two words, since they mean different things.

Comment: @HotLicks your answer is kind of "cheap". I always find fascinating thinking about why one language needs two words while another doesn't. E.g. some languages do not distinguish between *can* and *know*, *borrow* and *lend*, *boring* and *bored*, *fetch* and *bring* - and English has only one word *to be* where Spanish has three words. I think that you "solved" it too fast...

Comment: I appreciate the effort that went into framing the question, but your very title starts from a false premise ("nearly the same concept") and I am quite curious which other languages fail to distinguish between "protection" and "separation".  (Though it is certainly true that the "protection" aspect *comes* from being separated.)

Comment: You would have to check the Oxford English Dictionary for the earliest attestations of the word **insulation**  in the sense of "a barrier that blocks the flow (of air, of electricity, etc)"

Comment: The Q is based on a misconception.

Comment: @Kris: enlighten me then, please.

Comment: OED says of ***isolated*** (first cite 1751) *The French **isolé** was at first used unchanged or with **-d , isolé'd** .* And their first cite for **insulate** is 1752 *The Ryver of Avon so windeth aboute Oundale Toune that it almost **insulatithe** it, savyng a litle by West North West,* so they were clearly seen as different words (by implication, with different *derivations*) right from the outset. And we obviously use them completely differently today, so that was a useful distinction made long before we knew exactly *why* we'd need two words.

Comment: @Hellion: I have added links for you. In almost all the European languages I tried the insulation and isolation is expressed by one single word. Most probably it means that for many people it really is almost the same concept. Of course these languages allow you to further specify, but in a common situations you do not need it and you can live with a single word.

Comment: FWIW, it's not rare to find [cognate doublets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_(linguistics)) in several languages with intimately related meanings contrary to the economy principle. There are several of them in English in the linked page, and a few I can think of in Spanish are "oreja" and "aurícula", which are related only metaphorically, and "indudable" and "indubitable", which mean virtually the same thing.

Comment: Placing a prisoner in *isolation* is far different from placing him in *insulation*.

Comment: @HotLicks Not so far as it seems - ISOLATING the prisoner from the world is quite near to INSULATING him from the world.

Comment: But placing a prisoner in insulation implies packing him between batts of fiberglass.

Comment: @HotLicks or behind bars

Comment: Not in US English.

Answer (score 1):

The -atus ending insasmuch as it is formed from the past participle of the verb (and thereby conveys the idea of action-done-to) is  suited to the meaning "protected by means of a barrier";  the earlier borrowing from Latin **insulanus** (Middle English **insulan**, island-dwelling) shows an adjectival ending appended to nouns to convey the idea of origin or possession.

The insul-- form was already here since the mid 15th century.

The Middle English concept of "island-dweller" already went beyond the geographic definition to include the more abstract idea of not being subject to certain forces or influences:

*Eke, for he is a insulane, therefor he doth no subjeccion onto no man.*

The idea of "being shielded from" is lurking there.

The Latin-derived -ate ending was already productive in Middle English technical/scientific writing in the first quarter of the 15th century.